# K8S: convert "kubeadm init" command-line arguments to "--config" YAML

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, x509certificate, kubeadm, kube-apiserver

---

## Background

I'm attempting to configure a cluster via `kubeadm`. I normally create the (test) cluster via:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16
```

This parameter appears to eventually find its way into the static pod definition for the controllerManager (`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`):

```
- --cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

Larger portions of `sudo vim /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-controller-manager
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-controller-manager
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --allocate-node-cidrs=true
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
    - ...
    - --cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

---

## Question 1:

How can I pass this setting, `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` via a config file, i.e. `kubeadm init --config my_config.yaml`? I found a [sample config file template on an unofficial K8S documentation wiki](https://unofficial-kubernetes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/kubeadm/), but I can't seem to find any documentation at all that maps these command-line arguments to `kubeadm` to their `kubeadm_config.yaml` equivalents.

[There's also a document showing how I can create a baseline static pod definition/`yaml`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/) via `kubeadm config print init-defaults > kubeadm_config.yaml`, but again, no documentation that shows how to set `pod-network-cidr` by modifying and applying this `yaml` file (i.e. `kubeadm upgrade -f kubeadm_config.yaml`).

**Sample output of `kubeadm config view`:**

```
apiServer:
  extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns:
  type: CoreDNS
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.15.4
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  podSubnet: 10.244.0.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

---

## Question 2:

How can I do the above, but pass something like `--experimental-cluster-signing-duration=0h30m0s`? I'd like to experiment with tests involving manually/automatically renewing all `kubeadm`-related certs.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Accorindg to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#config-file):

> It’s possible to configure `kubeadm init` with a configuration file
>   instead of command line flags, and some more advanced features may
>   only be available as configuration file options. This file is passed
>   with the `--config` option.
>
> The default configuration can be printed out using the `kubeadm config print` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/).
>
> It is recommended that you migrate your old v1beta1 configuration to v1beta2 using the `kubeadm config migrate` [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/).
>
> During `kubeadm init`, kubeadm uploads the ClusterConfiguration object
>   to your cluster in a ConfigMap called kubeadm-config in the
>   kube-system namespace. This configuration is then read during `kubeadm
>   join`, `kubeadm reset` and `kubeadm upgrade`. To view this ConfigMap
>   call `kubeadm config view`.
>
> You can use `kubeadm config print` to print the default configuration
>   and `kubeadm config migrate` to convert your old configuration files
>   to a newer version. `kubeadm config images list` and `kubeadm config images pull` can be used to list and pull the images that kubeadm
>   requires.

Subnets are defined by `--pod-network-cidr` argument in kubeadm OR by a config file such as the example below below:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: InitConfiguration
api:
  advertiseAddress: 0.0.0.0
  bindPort: 6443
kubernetesVersion: v1.12.1
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
networking:
  podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/24
```

**2.** I was not able to find anything like this in the official documentation nor in other sources.

You instead can use [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/) to pass that kind of configuration.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thank you. [There is additional documentation from a Github help request from the `kubeadm` authors to help with point (2)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1825).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the cluster with the desired configurations and then just get the config.yaml like so:

```bash
kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system kubeadm-config > ./config.yaml
```

2. Pass in the extra args to the affected service.